# Trim a wav file

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, trim, naudio

I'm trying to trim a file using the code from [here](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.co.il/2009/09/trimming-wav-file-using-naudio.html)

```
 public static void TrimWavFile(string inPath, string outPath, TimeSpan cutFromStart, TimeSpan cutFromEnd)
 {
    using (WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader(inPath))
    {
        using (WaveFileWriter writer = new WaveFileWriter(outPath, reader.WaveFormat))
        {
            int bytesPerMillisecond = reader.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond / 1000;

            int startPos = (int)cutFromStart.TotalMilliseconds * bytesPerMillisecond;
            startPos = startPos - startPos % reader.WaveFormat.BlockAlign;

            int endBytes = (int)cutFromEnd.TotalMilliseconds * bytesPerMillisecond;
            endBytes = endBytes - endBytes % reader.WaveFormat.BlockAlign;
            int endPos = (int)reader.Length - endBytes; 

            TrimWavFile(reader, writer, startPos, endPos);
        }
    }
}

private static void TrimWavFile(WaveFileReader reader, WaveFileWriter writer, int startPos, int endPos)
{
    reader.Position = startPos;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (reader.Position < endPos)
    {
        int bytesRequired = (int)(endPos - reader.Position);
        if (bytesRequired > 0)
        {
            int bytesToRead = Math.Min(bytesRequired, buffer.Length);
            int bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                writer.WriteData(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote exactly whats in there but when I'm opening the file i trimmed it says he's corrupted.

How does this code works? The `while (reader.Position < endPos)` is always true and the `reader.Position` doesn't change.

**Edit 1**
The else if() are same as the else but i put it just to be sure.

```
while (reader.Position < end)
        {
            int bytesRequired = (int)(end - reader.Position);
            if (bytesRequired > 0)
            {
                int bytesToRead = Math.Min(bytesRequired, buffer.Length);
                int bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);
                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    writer.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                else if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                   break;
                }
            }
            else if (bytesRequired <= 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the soluton. I had to write *writer.Dispose()* after it was finished.
Like that:

```
public static void TrimWavFile(string inPath, string outPath, TimeSpan cutFromStart, TimeSpan cutFromEnd)
 {
    using (WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader(inPath))
    {
        using (WaveFileWriter writer = new WaveFileWriter(outPath, reader.WaveFormat))
        {
            int bytesPerMillisecond = reader.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond / 1000;

            int startPos = (int)cutFromStart.TotalMilliseconds * bytesPerMillisecond;
            startPos = startPos - startPos % reader.WaveFormat.BlockAlign;

            int endBytes = (int)cutFromEnd.TotalMilliseconds * bytesPerMillisecond;
            endBytes = endBytes - endBytes % reader.WaveFormat.BlockAlign;
            int endPos = (int)reader.Length - endBytes; 

            TrimWavFile(reader, writer, startPos, endPos);
            writer.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: strange - that's what the using statement should have done for you

Answer (score 1):

you should break out of the while loop if `bytesRequired <= 0` or if `bytesRead == 0`

Comment: I did it and I'm still getting this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDT0S.png
Do you have any idea why?

Comment: is the input file playable? what is the waveformat?

Comment: The input is playable and its a wav file.

Comment: I debugged the program and its not even entering the else and breaking the while loop. I added the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code you used it a bit outdated and has some bugs.
Here is an updated version (that works perfectly well for me):

```
private void Cut()
{
  var filename = @"G:\Voice\Samples\LongAudioFile.wav";
  FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filename);
  var outputPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(fi.Directory.FullName, string.Format("{0}_Shorter{1}", fi.Name.Replace(fi.Extension, ""), fi.Extension));

  TrimWavFile(filename, outputPath, TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
}

public static void TrimWavFile(string inPath, string outPath, TimeSpan duration)
{
  using (WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader(inPath))
  {
    using (WaveFileWriter writer = new WaveFileWriter(outPath, reader.WaveFormat))
    {
      float bytesPerMillisecond = reader.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond / 1000f;

      int startPos = 0;
      startPos = startPos - startPos % reader.WaveFormat.BlockAlign;

      int endBytes = (int)Math.Round(duration.TotalMilliseconds * bytesPerMillisecond);
      endBytes = endBytes - endBytes % reader.WaveFormat.BlockAlign;
      int endPos = endBytes;

      TrimWavFile(reader, writer, startPos, endBytes);
    }
  }
}

private static void TrimWavFile(WaveFileReader reader, WaveFileWriter writer, int startPos, int endPos)
{
  reader.Position = startPos;
  byte[] buffer = new byte[reader.BlockAlign * 1024];
  while (reader.Position < endPos)
  {
    int bytesRequired = (int)(endPos - reader.Position);
    if (bytesRequired > 0)
    {
      int bytesToRead = Math.Min(bytesRequired, buffer.Length);
      int bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);
      if (bytesRead > 0)
      {
        writer.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that in my case I need to get the audio from the start up to a certain point (ex: 1H).
if you want to get a specific section somewhere in the middle, just change:

```
int startPos = 0;
```

to

```
int startBytes = (int)Math.Round(startPoint.TotalMilliseconds * bytesPerMillisecond);
startBytes = startBytes - startBytes % reader.WaveFormat.BlockAlign;
int startPos = startBytes;
```